# Why does list.append(openpyxlObject) work , while list[index]=openpyxlObject doesnt?

Tags: python, list, object, openpyxl

So i have a function that's loading a bunch of excel files into memory:

```py
def batchLoader(files, openMode="o"): #loads files out of the array of files it is passed. Modes are either 'o'pen or 'n'ew file. 

    if len(openMode)==1: #lazy mode applier
        openMode=openMode*len(files)

    excelObjects=[] #array of excel objects we are gonna load
    for file, mode, index in zip(files, openMode, range(0,len(files))):

        if mode=="n": #if in newmode, create a blank file
            excelObjects[index]=openpyxl.Workbook()
            excelObjects[index].save(file)
        print(file,mode,index)
        try:   
            currentFile=openpyxl.load_workbook(file) #load the requested file
            excelObjects.append(currentFile)
            print('he')
        except:
            print('ho')
            fileErrorHandler(file, 'could not be loaded')
            sys.exit()
        fileErrorHandler(file,'has been loaded')

    return excelObjects
```

The code in the try statement works - so appending the generated excel object works just fine, but when i try to save it as you would normal data into a list object as i do in the "if mode==n" statement, it will return an error. Why?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `excelObjects` like this:

```py
excelObjects=[]
```

At this point, it's an empty list.

When the line `excelObjects[index]=openpyxl.Workbook()` is executed, it attempts to update the item at index `index` within `excelObjects`, which is still an empty list. Such an operation will raise an error, as it should, since we are trying to update something which has never been initialized. In other words, `index` is out of range in the expression `excelObjects[index]`.

In contrast, `excelObjects.append(...)` will do something more reasonable, which is to add space at the end of `excelObjects` to hold the object passed as an argument to `append()`.

If you were to change the initialization of `excelObjects` to `excelObjects=[None] * len(files)`, that would get rid of the error, but the logic in your code would also potentially cause `excelObjects[index]` to be updated for some but not all values of `index`, leaving null values at other positions in the list. This may cause `excelObjects` to be a less useful return value than if you use the `append()` approach.